# How to mount docker volume which is running in EC2 instance to EBS volume? What are the steps for that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-volume

Currently ec2 instance is running and inside that docker container is running.
I have 2 containers running in EC2 instance. 
1 - Aplication container.
2 - Data Base(CouchDb) container.
I need to store data which is in database to EBS volumes.
I have a docker-compose file and I'm bringing up containers using 'docker-compose up' command.

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "4200:4200"
     - "7020:7020"
    depends_on:
      couchdb:
        condition: "service_healthy"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app/app
  couchdb:
    image: "couchdb:1.7.1"
    ports:
     - "5984:5984"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:5984/"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 90s
        retries: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the EC2 instance directory with CouchDB container.

**Where to Store Data**

> Important note: There are several ways to store data used by
>   applications that run in Docker containers. We encourage users of the
>   couchdb images to familiarize themselves with the [options available](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb)
>
> Create a data directory on a suitable volume on your host system, e.g.
>   `/home/ec2-user/data`. Start your couchdb container like this:

```
$ docker run --name mycouchdb -v /home/ec2-user/data:/opt/couchdb/data -d couchdb:tag
```

> The `-v /home/ec2-user/data:/opt/couchdb/data` part of the command mounts the `/home/ec2-user/data` directory from the
>   underlying host system as `/opt/couchdb/data` inside the container,
>   where CouchDB by default will write its data files.

[CouchDB Store Data](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb)

**Update:**

In the case of docker-compose

```
  couchdb:
    image: "couchdb:1.7.1"
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/data:/opt/couchdb/data
    ports:
     - "5984:5984"
```

Comment: I have a docker-compose file and I'm bringing up containers using 'docker-compose up' command.

Docker compose file :
version: '2.1'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "4200:4200"
     - "7020:7020"
    depends_on:
      couchdb:
        condition: "service_healthy"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app/app
  couchdb:
    image: "couchdb:1.7.1"
    ports:
     - "5984:5984"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:5984/"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 90s
        retries: 9

Comment: Add `volumes: -/home/couchdb/data:/opt/couchdb/data` in the compose file

Comment: I added volumes in compose file.
I stopped and deleted the container.
Again when i give docker-compose up it shld take the data from that mounted /home/couchdb/data directory. But I'm not getting the data which is storred before deleting the container